# ClassCastException with mockito-inline

Tags: java, mockito, mockito-inline

I am using Mockito version 5.2.0.

With `mockito-inline`, the following code throws a `ClassCastException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  A a = mock(A.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
  String str = a.b().map(B::string).orElseThrow();
}

interface A {
  Optional<B> b();
}

interface B {
  String string();
}
```

Is this a bug?

The reason it throws a `ClassCastException` is that the expression `a.b().map(B::string).orElseThrow()` returns a `B`, not a `String`.
To me, it would be more logical for `a.b().map(B::string).orElseThrow()` to return `null`.